# insert ... if not exists - in a cassandra trigger

Tags: triggers, cassandra

I'm investigating using a cassandra trigger to make inserts into multiple tables when insert to a table occurs.

So there is one table where I'd like to use the

```
insert into tbl (...) values(...) if not exists;
```

I'd like to know how to apply this if not exists logic to a RowMutation in an ITrigger.  Is it possible?